# Suppose $K_{m,n}$ is a complete bipartite graph. Then $mn\ge m+n-1$.

Tags: graph-theory

> Suppose $K_{m,n}$ is a complete bipartite graph. Then $mn\ge m+n-1$.

Taking $m\ge1$ fixed. Applying induction on $n$.

$n=1$, Result hold trivially.

Assume result holds for $n=k$.

So, $mk \ge m+k-1$.
 We want to prove for $n=k+1$.That is we are adding one more vertex to other partite sets. So the number of edges will be increased by $m$. We know that $m\ge 1$. Adding $m$ on both sides of our assumed inequality. We get, $mk+m \ge m+k-1+m$. Also we have $m\ge 1$. Add $m+k-1$ on both sides. We get $m+k-1+m\ge m+k$. Hence, by induction, Result holds for all positive integers. $\because$ $m,n$ are symmetric, we can do this for $n\ge 1$. Did I write the correct proof for the given result? How do I prove the result without induction?

Comment: This question doesn't make very much sense to me. Are $m$ and $n$ pulling double duty as the size of the partite sets and also the number of vertices/edges, or something like that? On the face of it, the question seems to just be asking "Prove that $mn \geq m + n - 1$ when $m,n \geq 1$", and the complete bipartite graph is totally irrelevant.

Comment: Prove that $mn≥m+n−1$ when $m,n≥1$. Actually, I was proving the result for a complete bipartite graph.

Comment: What's your definition of "*complete bipartite graph*"? In particular, does it exclude $K_{4,0}$?

Answer (score 0):

By [König's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_(set_theory)), if $\kappa_i,\lambda_i$ $(i\in I)$ are cardinal numbers such that $\lambda_i\gt\kappa_i$ for each $i\in I,$ then $\prod_{i\in I}\lambda_i\gt\sum_{i\in I}\kappa_i.$ In particular, if $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2$ are nonnegative integers such that $a_1\gt b_1$ and $a_2\gt b_2,$ then $a_1b_1\gt a_2+b_2.$ If $m,n$ are positive integers then, since $m\gt m-1\ge0$ and $n\gt n-1\ge0,$ it follows that $mn\gt(m-1)+(n-1)=m+n-2.$ Since $mn$ is an integer, this means that $mn\ge m+n-1.$

Comment: what about my proof. is it correct?